# Impossible to install Pytorch==0.3.1 for ubuntu 22.04 (install old script dependancies)

Tags: pytorch, python-3.6, rollback, ubuntu-22.04

I am struggling like hell to make old python scripts work, and it is driving me crazy.

I truly thought scripts from 4 years ago wouldn't be so hard to run today...

So I am trying to run this project : https://github.com/jthsieh/DDPAE-video-prediction

For which there are these recommendations :
All code was developed and tested on Python 3.6, PyTorch 0.3.1, and Pyro 0.2.
To view results, you need to install tensorflow and tensorbaordX.

So first things first, I installed python3.6, which already is a little tricky.

But module PyTorch0.3.1 does not exist and it seems really difficult to find out.

I don't understand why there isn't a way to go back in time with python in a virtual machin.

Is here a simple way to do this ?

Do I have to do all dependencies, roll back and everything by hand ?

Please folks, I am so tired of trying to make old scientific projects work....

I tried to download the package from Pytorch website, but didn't find any Linux version...
I tried to use the pip version in the python 3.6 folder, and surprisingly it didn't change the output of
`pip install torch==0.3.1` or `pip install pytorch==0.3.1`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest would be to go to [pytorch whl](https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch/), download the pytorch version you want (in your case 0.31) and install pytorch with pip and the file.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. I tried to install it from *.whl, in a virtual env, on python 3.6, but I get this error :
```ERROR: torch-0.3.1-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.```

I am sooooo tired of the lack of any backward compatibility in Python, it is insanely complicated to combine python, ubuntu and a scientific career together !!!!

Comment: Is there a map of all versions of packages-pythons-ubuntu to be able to KNOW which one to take to install everything ?
You have to check along the code and if one breaks, you have to erase everything to restart with a different version (that you often cannot get anymore)....

Answer (score 0):

Or as an alternative to install old versions of pytorch, try to use a Docker image.
Just add a `Dockerfile` to your project local folder with the needed versions of pytorch and nvidia.

Example of `Dockerfile` (to be adapted to your versions):

```
FROM nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:20.12-py3
FROM ubuntu:20.04
FROM python:3.9-buster
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, I will give it a try, but doesn't the docker image have to be done by the person who posted the code on git hub ?

Comment: You also can do it. (edited above)